# my website go in 404 page when i put this code in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I need this

> www.mydomain.com/apple
>  www.mydomain.com/banana
>   www.mydomain.com/mango
>  to
>   www.mydomain.com/search.php?q=apple
>   www.mydomain.com/search.php?q=banana
>   www.mydomain.com/search.php?q=mango

This is not working 
My website go in **404 page**
My **.htaccess**

> Options +FollowSymLinks
>  RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*) search.php?q=$1

Comment: If you want url parameters like that, you are probably looking for $_GET in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#If the request is not for an existent directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#And file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Then rewrite the request 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.